# sort by first group element dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

probably a simple answer but proving surprisingly challenging. My data looks like the following, state-wise percentages occurring over three years:

```
State<-c('Assam','Bihar','Chandigarh','Delhi','Goa')
2012<-c(96, 95, 94, 92, 99)
2013<-c(97, 97, 94, 93, 100)
2014<-c(97, 98, 96, 95, 100)

df<-data.frame(State, 2013, 2013, 2014)
```

I'm trying to group it by State, arrange the years, and then arrange state groups by ascending 2012 percentages. Also need a separate df that will arrange states by their 2014 percentages.

Here's what I have:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

dfmelt<-melt(df, id = 'State')
colnames(dfmelt)<-c('State','Year','Percent')

dfmelt<-dfmelt %>% arrange(Percent) %>% group_by(State) %>% arrange(Year)
```

Tried a million combinations of last line and can't crack it. Have looked at similar questions but with no summarizing or mutation here, just pure rearranging, I'm stuck.

Ultimately I'm creating 2 dot plots, one ranking states on Y axis by 2012 %'s and one by 2014 %'s. Figure I need the dataframe in exact order for ggplot to do this, right? Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Thanks!

Comment: your data doens't work - you can't assign a vector of numbers to another number : `2012 <- c(96, 95, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data creation code does not run, and you have 2013 repeated.

Here is the code to generate that data:

```
State <- c('Assam','Bihar','Chandigarh','Delhi','Goa')
p2012 <- c(96, 95, 94, 92, 99)
p2013 <- c(97, 97, 94, 93, 100)
p2014 <- c(97, 98, 96, 95, 100)
df <- data.frame(State, p2012, p2013, p2014)
```

You can then do the following to receive a data frame (long format) sorted by state groups in the order of 2012 percentage:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(Year, Percentage, -State) %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(Percentage2012 = Percentage[Year == 'p2012']) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Percentage2012, State, Year) %>%
  select(-Percentage2012)
```

Resulting data frame as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]

        State   Year Percentage
       (fctr) (fctr)      (dbl)
1       Delhi  p2012         92
2       Delhi  p2013         93
3       Delhi  p2014         95
4  Chandigarh  p2012         94
5  Chandigarh  p2013         94
6  Chandigarh  p2014         96
7       Bihar  p2012         95
8       Bihar  p2013         97
9       Bihar  p2014         98
10      Assam  p2012         96
11      Assam  p2013         97
12      Assam  p2014         97
13        Goa  p2012         99
14        Goa  p2013        100
15        Goa  p2014        100
```

Hope this helps. Of course, you can create a 2014 data frame by simply modifying the above code slightly.

Comment: note to OP, `tidyr::gather` is similar to `reshape2::melt`

Comment: Aware. I like combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr` as you can integrate them into the same pipeline. :)

Comment: yeah me to - it was more for the original poster who may not be familiar with it, as they were originally using `reshape2`

Comment: Thanks, yes, also aware of gather: but melt so easy in this context. Probably more elegant to use tidyr. Sorry for errors in df. Was hasty in recreating it here, real dataframe much larger.

Comment: You can remove the `tidyr` code from that pipeline and get same result by first converting to long format using `melt`.

Comment: @Gopala Thanks! This works great as is/with melt. Can you explain intuitively what the '-' operator is doing in both contexts? (-State in the gather function and then -Percentage2012) ?

Comment: Also, @Gopala, just tried this on an identically structured dataset and got the error `Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1` ...thoughts?

Comment: Hyphen (minus) is de-selecting that column and only retaining the rest. You can affirmatively list out the ones you want to keep. Since in this case, only one to be rid, I used the 'minus' on that column name. On the error, make sure you use stringsAsFactors = FALSE in reading the data frame (or convert the State and such to be non-factor variables). Hard to debug without having the data at hand.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to order the axis in a `ggplot` you can do it with your `df` as-is.

You just need to make use of 'reorder' in `ggplot`

```
df<-data.frame("State" = c('Assam','Bihar','Chandigarh','Delhi','Goa'),
                             "2012" = c(96, 95, 94, 92, 99),
                             "2013" = c(97, 97, 94, 93, 100),
                             "2014" = c(97, 98, 96, 95, 100))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(State, X2012), y=X2014)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```